# mysql is not responsing on xampp

Tags: php, mysql

I am using XAMPP server for my php/mysql projects. Today, when I tried to start apache and mysql, mysql failed to open saying "this may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, improper privileges...", and my phpmyadmin page says "#2002 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."

I am nervous because I have an important database there and I cannot open it nor I have a backup of it. I am looking for your valuable comments.

p.s. I have installed Python version 2.7.6 yesterday. Can Python block the default mysql port 3306?

I am on windows 7 os

Comment: Nope. Python cannot block mysql. Have you tried to access mysql from the terminal?

Comment: Disabled any firewalls to see if that is the problem?  Tried changing MySQL port from default in configuration?  Tried starting the server with administrator privileges?

Comment: no I am not running Skype..

Comment: I have disabled my firewalls, but the problem persists.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about server-related issues and would be a better fit for [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: @user2714362 I asked the skype question because for a second, I confused your problem with one I had with apache.  But then I remembered it was apache, and thus deleted my question because it was no longer relevant.

Answer (score 1):

use

> netstat -b -p TCP

to view the process is using port 3306